# How to Integrate FlexPaper With Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, flexpaper

I am trying to implement FlexPaper in my sample project and it contains Pdf Files.

After Reading the FlexPaper documentation I have found that.. We need to publish the document first [Click Here](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs.jsp) I have 500 pdf documents in my project so it will be a pain to publish those files. Did i understand correctly ? If yes what are the alternative of not going through publishing mode to publish pdf files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have posted the same question to the FlexPaper Team and they reverted me back saying place all the pdf files on the pdf folder so no need to upload the document.

Thanks